# jQuery.ajax() statusCode detect connection lost or offline

Tags: jquery, ajax

`statusCode` takes an object with numeric status codes as the keys and functions as the values, ex:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/points/' + geocode['place_id'],
    statusCode: {
      409: () => {
        alert('Duplicate');
      },
      204: () => {
        valid = true;
      }
    }
  });
```

How can this be used to detect if a request fails because the user goes off-line? I don't suppose jQuery has a status code for this scenario (it wasn't mentioned in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))?

Comment: What is it that might time out? Are you trying to test whether an Ajax request has timed out before a response is received?

Comment: @nnnnnn No response from server, connection lost, etc.

Comment: *"it wasn't mentioned in the docs"* - Yes it was, in the very page you linked to, which tells you how to specify a timeout in milliseconds, and that if no response is received by then the error handler will be called with a status of `"timeout"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, it does, which doesn't answer the question concerning statusCode.

Comment: But that `statusCode` is specifying possible codes of the response, and if it timed out you didn't get a response but as per my previous comment the error handler would've been called with status `"timeout"`.

Comment: @nnnnnn `as per my previous comment the error handler would've been called with status "timeout"` I tried it, that's not what I'm seeing. Both 404 and offline results in textStatus of "error", whereas I want to differentiate 404's from offline

Answer (score 0):

Timeout will not raise any status code but you may handle it with `error` callback:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/api/points/' + geocode['place_id'],
  statusCode: {
    409: () => {
      alert('Duplicate');
    },
    204: () => {
      valid = true;
    }
  }
}).error(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
  if ( textStatus == 'timeout' ) {
    // timeout occured
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not working when I go offline, `textStatus` is just "error", which is the same as the textStatus from a 404. Also, jQuery changed the `.error` to `.fail`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides `.fail()`:

```
$.ajax({
    // Your code
}).fail(function () {
   console.dir("Trouble connecting: check your connection and try again.")
   //See it in action by switching to Offline in Chrome DevTools
   //Add any other custom message via jQuery here
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/